Delphi applications cannot connect to MySQL on Windows 11
We currently have a large number of Delphi applications that communicate with a MySQL 8 server, which we cannot get to work on Windows 11. They currently connect correctly on Windows 10.

Delphi 12.1
MySQL Server 8.0.35 (64 bit)
libMySQL 5.7.37 (32 bit)
Development machine: Windows 10 Enterprise 22H2
Deployment machine: Windows 11 Enterpise 23H2

The applications are all distributed with the libmysql.dll in the same folder as the executable along with an FDConnectionDefs.ini defining the connections.
As I understand it, as the applications are compiled as 32-bit applications, they need to use the 32-bit MySQL driver, which the 5.7.37 version is the last available. When we try to run any of the applications we get the error:

Cannot load vendor library [...libmysql]. The specified module cannot be found

along with a hint to:

check PATH or EXE directories and x86 bitness.

We get the same error, but with the correct path, if we include an FDDrivers.ini in the EXE folder.
FDAdministrator exhibits the same error if we copy it to the target machine with the same DLL and INI files in its folder.
Edit
Following suggestions we have tested with ProcMon and found the following

The applications are correctly finding and loading the supplied libmysql.dll file in the EXE directory

The Windows 11 version is failing on trying to load libmysqld.dll in addition to the libmysql.dll. This is what is causing the error message.

The Windows 10 version makes no attempt to load libmysqld



you can use tools like depwalk and procmon to find the issue.

I think libmysql.dll requires a Visual C++ redistributable to be installed. We install the x86 / 2015 version with our Delphi 12.1 program that uses the same client library, but I'm not 100% sure thats for libmysql.dll. But it may be worth checking you have that installed and try installing it if not.

There's a comment to that effect on the DocWiki but when I downloaded the version that was suggested WIndows told me that there was already a version installed....
We are currentky doing a vanilla install and will check that and procmon

Sysinternals' Process Monitor can be used to see what it is trying to open.

"already a version installed" - yes, but probably x64 instead of x86, which somewhere sits in your PATH environment variable and gets pulled first. That's why you should use ProcMon to check which DLLs are actually loaded. Likewise your application can test loading the target DLLs to then inform the user from which files got loaded (instead of just assuming the intended way will happen). Applications are only as good as they can self reflect what currently happens.

Note for testing: With Windows 11 Pro or better you can enable the Windows Sandbox to get a fresh Windows environment where any changes vanish when it is closed. Good for confirming you are installing all that is needed on a fresh/clean system.

It turns out that the issue is the version of the Visual Studio Redistributable that we had installed. The latest x86 redistributatle, that we had installed, does not work.
However the 2013 version does work. I will try the 2015 version as suggested by @re0sless
